# node js how to auto call of any getting function in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

On the time of page loaded get_switch() function which globally created  on app.js page will be call then return a method. i want to execute these return methods.

demo.js

```
const return_functions = get_switch('BTC');

function get_btc()
{
    console.log('btc');
}


function get_bch()
{
    console.log('bch');

}
```

app.js

```
 global.get_switch=function(coin_name){

 switch(coin_name){

  case 'BTC':
  return 'get_btc()';
  break;


  case 'BCH':
  return 'get_bth()';
  break;

  default:
  console.log('default');
  }

 }
```

As shown in example above i have passed BTC in get_switch. and that function return us get_btc() function. so i want to call get_btc function on same time.

If this is not possible in this way so please guide me with your idea and suggest me how can i do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store all function into a class, and then call them using the name of the currency.

I've added something else tho, which is the use of an enumerate to handle your currencies.

```js
class CurrencyHandlingClass {
  // Store all currency type into an enumerate
  static get CURRENCY_TYPES() {
    return {
      BTC: 'Btc',
      BTH: 'Bth',
    };
  }

  // Method to get Btc
  static getBtc() {
    console.log('btc');
  }

  // Method to get Bhc
  static getBth() {
    console.log('bth');
  }
}

// Here the name of the function you wanna call
const currencyName1 = CurrencyHandlingClass.CURRENCY_TYPES.BTC;
const currencyName2 = CurrencyHandlingClass.CURRENCY_TYPES.BTH;

// Execute the method
CurrencyHandlingClass[`get${currencyName1}`]();
CurrencyHandlingClass[`get${currencyName2}`]();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just invoke the functions directly

```
function get_btc() {}

function get_bch() {}

global.get_switch = function (coin_name) {

 switch(coin_name){

  case 'BTC':
  return get_btc();
  break;


  case 'BCH':
  return get_bch();
  break;

  default:
  console.log('default');
  }

 }
```

Comment: but get_switch function is calling from another route.so i have to use return function there .